# Angular 4 (with i18n) app deployment on azure blob

Tags: json, angular, azure, internationalization, azure-blob-storage

I have been trying to deploy an angular 4 application to azure blob storage. After deploying the app, there is an issue with i18n (translation) part of the application.

en.json file and fr.json file are not working after deploying the application to azure blob. (Locally translation works)

When i check the inspect element, following error comes. 
[image]

When i check the direct url for the translation file, it shows the json file on the browser.

Comment: Is your blob container publicly available without authenticating the request?

Comment: Yes it is available. But when I load the json file once from inspect element once, it shows the translation. But if it's a fresh web page start, json files not loading

Comment: Can you please share the URL of your app?